# Loading bar in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progress-bar, loading, web-deployment

I would like to have a loading overlay element in my Vue project, but what is the correct pattern to implement it.
I mean, how the browser download render and display just that loading element (possibly with a loading bar but not mandatory), and just after takes care of the rest of my contents, to then tell me that those are ready and I can hide the loading page overlay?
Thanks